# Conversion Error from 'unsigned __int64' to 'unsigned __int64 *' - Pybind11

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, pybind11

After downloading this https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/archive/v2.2.3.zip 
and creating a simple cpp file:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) { return i + j; }

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring
    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

with

[image]

I get this error

[image]

```
Error C2446 '<': no conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'unsigned __int64 *' in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector line 2326
```

Would anybody know what this could be referring to, and possibly how to fix it?

---

As requested, here the full error log:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Test_CreatePythonBindings, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>example.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector(2326): error C2446: '<': no conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'unsigned __int64 *'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector(2326): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector(2325): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::_Vb_const_iterator<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>> &std::_Vb_const_iterator<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>>::operator +=(__int64)'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector(2545): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Vb_const_iterator<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>> &std::_Vb_const_iterator<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>>::operator +=(__int64)' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector(2490): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vb_const_iterator<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector(3094): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vb_iterator<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector(3093): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<bool,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const bool &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
1>c:\pybind11-2.2.3\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(513): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<bool,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const bool &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
1>c:\pybind11-2.2.3\include\pybind11\cast.h(1806): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<bool,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\vector(2326): warning C4554: '&': check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence
1>Done building project "Test_CreatePythonBindings.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Switch to the "Build" view in lower pane and paste the text here. There will be more information there. This error originated from vector implementation but it's not the place where it happened.

Comment: Also, try and produce a [mcve] (note the "Complete" there).

Comment: @BJovke Added the full output, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps, the error is in "cast.h". I have to take a look at it.

Comment: Actually the error is in "pybind11.h", but the lines in the error log you posted do not match the lines from ZIP file you referenced in your question. So the code is probably not the same. Can you redownload the ZIP file, build with it again and post the errors again?

Comment: Re-downloaded and updated include screenshot + error log

Comment: `call.args_convert.push_back(false);` in pybind11.h gives this error. `call` is `struct function_call` and `args_convert` is `std::vector<bool>` so this should work. My guess is that some of the Python's header/source files or some other files you're including are redefining some of these things somehow. Can you search python directory and any other header files you've included for `function_call` and `args_convert`?

Comment: I think I've found something. In cpython GitHub repository there's a `function_call` function in file `Objects/funcobject.c`. This might interfere with pybind11 but I'm not sure since I don't have Python installed.

Comment: I've pasted the search output here: https://pastebin.com/raw/s5qckwVu

Comment: As for *funcobject*, I only found c:\Program Files\Python36\include\funcobject.h which I pasted here https://pastebin.com/raw/yFz58HeG for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a VS 2017 issue related to

```
  std::vector<bool>
```

Separate question asked here:
[Pushback on vector<bool> fails - VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816574/pushback-on-vectorbool-fails-vs-2017)